# Odd Python List Behaviour During Assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have an empty list initialized

```
lst = []
```

and at a later stage it may end up populated something like

```
lst = [{'sender':'personA', 'receiver':'personB', 'amount':12}]
```

Then I need a copy of it with an additional value appended so I call something like

```
new_lst = lst[:].append({'sender':'personA', 'receiver':'personB', 'amount':12})
```

but I find that `new_lst` is assigned to `None` and I don't understand why. Python should be passing me back a list which does indeed have an append attribute and then making the assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `list.append()` function doesn't return a value, it simply modifies the list in place, hence `new_lst` is assigned to `None`.

If you want to fix this while still using the `append()` function, you could just append the value after you've copied the list.

```
new_lst = lst[:]
lst.append(blah)
```